# How to better optimize my find function?

Tags: java, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I need to create a `find()` function to search a LinkedList of movie titles, but I can't. Maybe I did something wrong in my code... Anyone got any pointers?

```
@Override
public Movie find(String name) {
    if (name == null) {
        System.out.println("Not found");
    } else if (name != null) {
        System.out.println(name + " found!");
    }
    return movies.getFirst();
}
```

Comment: So where exactly are you doing the searching?

Comment: If this code is working, you should ask how to optimise it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Your code doesn't make that much sense. If you pass **any** String (or even null) into that function, it will always give you the first movie. If pass `null` in, it will say "Not found" and then give you a movie back anyway.

Comment: You need to iterate on your LinkedList

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how the Movie class is laid out, but assuming its a linked list of movies, here is code that iterates through the list until it finds the movie with the title you are searching for (returning null if no such matching movie is found).

```
Movie movie = movies.getFirst();
while (movie != null) {
  if (movie.getTitle().equals(name)) {
    return movie;
  }
  movie = movie.getNext();
}
return null;
```